# windows-issue with GWT Eclipse?

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, eclipse-rcp

```
Issues:   
 {
        i). package com.example.helloworld.server;

             @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        ii).   public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    GreetingService 
 }
```

(1). The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse. Fix the build path then try building this project.

(2). The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

I got the above two issues whenever i had just created "New Web Application Project' (GWT), And i didn't add any extra code in created project. I am new to this concepts, please help me what i have to do for solving above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `gwt-servlet.jar`  to your `classpath`

https://www.versioneye.com/package/com~google~gwt--gwt-servlet/version/0

Make sure your `gwt-user-jar` and `servelt-jar` should be same version

Answer (score 0):

```
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
```

Essentially means some some of the jars which are required/present in the hierarchy of `HttpServletResponse` class are not present in the build-path.

To fix this, put your move over the red-cross icon of the eclipse error. It will tell the name of the class. Add the jar containing that class to the build-path.